# Debugging a widget before launching the app

Tags: android, widget, android-studio

I have an app with a widget. If you go into the app settings and clear the data, then lay a widget on the home screen before actually running the app, it crashes. I need to be able to debug the widget without launching the main app. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the run configuration of your application, under `Activity`, check `Do not launch Activity`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not getting any connection to the widget that way. It just goes straight to the crash without hitting my breakpoints.

Comment: Not entirely sure why that's happening, but you could try to put a `Debug.waitForDebugger();` right before your first breakpoint (this is just guesswork).

Comment: Ok, correction. It is making a connection, but still not hitting any breakpoints before a crash.

Comment: Ok, while we're at it, can you tell me why my custom Application class's onCreate is never getting fired? >.<

Comment: What is the crash you're getting? And did you specify your `Application` class in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Yes, I did specify my Application class. The crash is a NullPointerException from calling SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(). I'm guessing I'm constructing the SQLiteOpenHelper with a context that is inappropriate.

Comment: Ok, nevermind that last one. Apparently, it IS using my custom Application class, but this setting to not launch the activity when I start the debugger prevents the debugger from picking up the first ticks of the application, so the onCreate gets completed before the debugger attaches. And Debug.waitfordebugger doesn't help. This means it's not a useful solution for debugging the widget...

Comment: Ok, I figured out that if I have a loop that spins a million times before the widget actually starts, then I can catch it with a breakpoint. So I'll go ahead and mark yours as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I guess that the widget starts a bit faster than normal Activities, so the debugger has no time to attach.